# обработка php переменной перед выводом

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток

Собственно, давно хотел задать такой вопрос. Читаю ячейку, приравниваю к переменной. Далее следует вывод на экран. В переменной содержится код html. Можно ли поправить этот код перед выводом?

далее, т.к. на хэшкоде в обычном тексте скрываются некоторые символы, напишу в коде:

1. Можно ли, считать все от `<style>` до `</style>`, все что между заменить на переменную в которой у меня стили?
2. Можно ли, найти все `<a ...>текст</a>` и сделать `<a href="http://hashcode.ru/page.php?paramparam=текст">текст</a>` ?

p.s. интересует решение прежде всего на php, но не против и других решений

Comment: а регулярка ныне не в моде?

Comment: хэшкоде в обычном тексте скрываются некоторые символы// Есть экранирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Используйте регулярные выражения](http://phpforum.ru/index.php?showtopic=15291)
Это конечно не самые быстрые функции, так что не стоит их использовать повсеместно. Но для каких-то глобальных единичных задач вполне сойдёт.
[Ещё можно почитать здесь](http://php.su/functions/?page=cat_regvars)

P.s.
Имхо, в [Camel Book](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/147137/) лучше всего рассказано про регулярные выражения. Всё-таки perl создавался для работы с текстовыми данными.